# Делаю чат бота для телеграм на Telebot, python, хочу узнать как сделать так чтобы бот отвечал не только на ключевые слова а и на предложения

Tags: python, telebot

Пример: Ичика привет
Бот: Привет
Это я сделал и более, но хочу чтобы обращались не ключевыми словами которые добавляю в массив а и "Ичика [Предложение пользователя]" И будет ответ "Текст: "Текст пользователя""

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то могу предложить вам такую конструкцию

```
def echo(message):
    if message.text[:5] == "Ичика" # ну тоесть к боту идёт обращение      
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text =  message.text[6:])
```

Ну и если вы напишете "Ичика пошли гулять" то в ответ вы получите "пошли гулять"
Разумеется если не обратится по имени то ничего не произойдёт, но если требуется в любом случае получать ответ от бота то можно добавить это

```
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = f"{message.from_user.first_name}, обращайтесь ко мне по имени! ")
```

В итоге ответ будет в вашем случае" Богдан, обращайтесь ко мне по имени! "

Надеюсь что я правильно понял ваш вопрос, а если нет то будем разбираться)

Comment: Огромное спасибо)